# Is there any way to use the Japanese IME in the US locale in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ime

Windows used to allow any available input method on any locale.

Now, the best I am able to get for a default is a Japanese keyboard layout. I can switch to Japanese IME manually afterwards but EN(JA) and EN(US)(after I removed it!) layouts keep popping up and are completely useless when the regular IME is a superset.

I know I could change my default language, but just because I can read Japanese doesn't mean I want to get irrelevant Google search results and badly translated apps.

Answer (score 0):

On a Win 10 system, open up **Start** → **Settings** → **Time & Language** → select **Region & language** on the left.  You should now see two setting groups: **Country or region** on the top, which you'll probably want to leave set to **United States** -- this affects things like which language apps will use for the UI.  Under that, you'll see the **Languages** settings.  I have only **日本語** ("Japanese") here.  With this setup, I can use the system and browse the internet in English, and I still get the IME for when I want to type in Japanese.